# Problem with request.getSession

Tags: java, servlets

I have a servlet LogMeOut.java where I am writing the following code:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if (session != null){
   //statements to delete my cookies //
   session.invalidate();
}
```

My problem is when I am calling the LogMeOut for the first time from a jsp, it gives a request object with no session. So my `session.invalidate` is not working.
But if I go back to my jsp and then call the same LogMeOut, this time the request object contains the correct session and it works.
Any idea why? Or where should I start looking?

Answer (score 3):

If you call `getSession(false)` on a request with no existing session, then it will return `null`. This is [expected, documented behaviour](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29).

If you call `getSession(true)` or just `getSession()`, then a session will be created if none exists.

Executing a JSP will generally also create a session automatically, so the next time your code is executed, a session will be present.

However, if all you want to do is invalidate an existing session, then your code looks fine to me - no need to create a session just to immediately invalidate it.

Comment: Yes, but I want to invalidate the session in the first time I am calling the servlet, but that does not seem to happen. It happens only in the second time I call my servlet. How do I make sure that I get the correct request with not-null session in the first call?